# FN control for screen brightness doesn't work in 16.10

Tags: grub2, keyboard, brightness, 16.10

I'm running Ubuntu 16.10 on an ASUS ZenBook Flip UX360CA. I googled some fixes for how to get the FN/keyboard control of the screen brightness to work, but none of them have worked for me. Any suggestions for what I can do?

The result of: `ls /sys/class/backlight` is `intel_backlight`.

I tried editing `/etc/default/grub` and changing `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"` to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash video.use_native_backlight=1"`

I also tried changing the line to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_osi=vendor"`

Each time, I ran `sudo grub-update` and rebooted, which resulted in no changes.

I tried making a file `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf` with the following contents.

```
Section "Device"
    Identifier  "card0"
    Driver      "intel"
    Option      "Backlight"  "intel_backlight"
    BusID       "PCI:0:2:0"
EndSection
```

I logged out and then back in, which also didn't have any effects.

Please help!

Comment: Try to add boot option `acpi_osi=Linux` then update grub and restart.

Comment: I ended up reinstalling Ubuntu but with 16.04. I'll try these options again and report back.

Comment: Update: I just gave up and did another fresh reinstall of 16.04. I had to do multiple reinstalls because I ran into the following problems: I kept getting a screen flicker, I got a kernel panic (but the computer booted the next time), I used Boot Repair but got a message I didn't understand about how one of my boot files are from the start of the disk. I'm just hoping this installation doesn't die/crash randomly in the future.